# "xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found" when run in jenkins

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, sax

So I'm working towards having automated staging deployments via Jenkins and Ansible. Part of this is using a script called [ec2.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) from ansible in order to dynamically retrieve a list of matching servers to deploy to.

SSH-ing into the Jenkins server and running the script from the jenkins user, the script runs as expected. However, running the script from within jenkins leads to the following error:

```
ERROR: Inventory script (ec2/ec2.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Deploy API/workspace/deploy/ec2/ec2.py", line 1262, in <module>
Ec2Inventory()
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Deploy API/workspace/deploy/ec2/ec2.py", line 159, in __init__
self.do_api_calls_update_cache()
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Deploy API/workspace/deploy/ec2/ec2.py", line 386, in do_api_calls_update_cache
self.get_instances_by_region(region)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Deploy API/workspace/deploy/ec2/ec2.py", line 417, in get_instances_by_region
reservations.extend(conn.get_all_instances(filters = { filter_key : filter_values }))
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Deploy API/workspace/deploy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 585, in get_all_instances
max_results=max_results)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Deploy API/workspace/deploy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 681, in get_all_reservations
[('item', Reservation)], verb='POST')
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Deploy API/workspace/deploy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1181, in get_list
xml.sax.parseString(body, h)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py", line 43, in parseString
parser = make_parser()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py", line 93, in make_parser
raise SAXReaderNotAvailable("No parsers found", None)
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found
```

I don't know too much about python, so I'm not sure how to debug this issue further.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the issue was to do with Jenkins overwriting the default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. By `unset`ting that variable before running python, I was able to make the python app work!

Comment: How exactly do you do that?

Comment: Check out the documentation on using the unset command in bash